# HackerRank - Left Rotation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, array

I'm looking to learn more about data structures, time complexity, and efficient algorithms. I have solved the [Left Rotation Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem)
on HackerRank using JavaScript. I am looking to see ways to optimize the time complexity. I feel like I have a lot to learn, as don't grok Big O.

```
function main() {
    const nd = readLine().split(' ')
    const numbers = parseInt(nd[0], 10)
    const rotations = parseInt(nd[1], 10)
    const arr = readLine().split(' ').map(aTemp => parseInt(aTemp, 10))
    const front = arr.slice(0, rotations)
    const back = arr.slice(rotations, numbers)
    const new_arr = back.concat(front)
    console.log(new_arr.join(' '))
}
```

I feel like this likely has bad time complexity, as under the hood, I believe the `slice` function uses a loop and has a time complexity of \$O(n)\$. In addition, I'm unsure of how JavaScript implements the merge from the `concat` method under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

#### Review

- Since you are building the array yourself, as opposed to you get a source array from a consumer of your method, I don't think you should create a new array, but rather just adapt the source array. This way, you could avoid `slice` and `concat` altogether.
- The number of `rotations` is an integer. However, reading the description behind the link tells use it's clamped between `1` <= `rotations` <= `nd`. There is a slight optimization here. If `rotations` = `nd` you don't have to do anything, since a rotation is circular. An elegant way to check this is to normalize `rotations` as `rotations = rotations % nd;` assuming you have already checked `rotations` againsts the clamped range. if `rotations = 0`, don't rotate.
- There's another optimization if `nd` < `2`, then any rotation is the source itself.